# Is it possible to using fwrite from data.table in R to write a table with sep=""

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to write a table to disk using fwrite from data.table where there is no seperator between fields, e.g.

```
data.table::fwrite(mtcars, "test.out", sep="", quote=F, row.names=F, col.names=F)
```

producing:

```
2161601103.92.6216.460144
2161601103.92.87517.020144
22.84108933.852.3218.611141
21.462581103.083.21519.441031
18.783601753.153.4417.020032
18.162251052.763.4620.221031
14.383602453.213.5715.840034
24.44146.7623.693.19201042
22.84140.8953.923.1522.91042
```

However, running this command gives:

```
Error in fwrite(mtcars, "test.out", sep = "", quote=F, row.names=F, col.names=F) : 
  is.character(sep) && length(sep) == 1L && nchar(sep) == 1L is not TRUE
```

It seems like this isn't possible for some reason. Does anyone know a workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Are you opposed to pasting the columns together before saving (e.g., `mtcars[, .(do.call(paste0, .SD))]`? Or, if you don't keep it as a `data.table` (i.e., don't use a list in j), you can use `writeLines()` or a similar function.

Comment: I am converting genetic data files between different formats and the software I am using has quite an irregular file format where the fields aren't delimited. representing the data this way isn't uncommon in genetics.

Comment: how do you know when one field has finished already and next started?

Comment: sahwahn, if the other software doesn't use commas, then it must use *something* to differentiate fields in a row. This might be fixed-width, binary, etc ... in which case there are functions to do that. But once written with no `sep`, there is entirely too much ambiguity in distinguishing fields. For instance, your first mtcars value of `2161601103.92.6216.460144` ... which of those numbers correspond to which columns? (Hint: some floating-point numbers have been truncated.)